# How to fix the volume filesystem root has only 0 bytes disk space remaining

Tags: filesystem

I got a warning saying `the filesystem root has only 800mb disk space remaining`, I ignored it. About 10 minutes later I restarted for something else, and when it loads the desktop it now says `the filesystem root has only 0mb disk space remaining`. And as you would expect, the system is hanging and I can't do much.

I really need to get data off there and or somehow fix it, can anyone help?

Unlike the other question which was answered I can't open a terminal.

Comment: Can you write `df` in the terminal if possible, and add the output to your question?

Comment: i can't open terminal seemingly, the ctrl-alt-t doesn't do anything

Comment: You can try booting from a `Live Ubuntu Usb` and try to recover data from there.

Comment: @Russo from there can I delete stuff on the file system?

Comment: @chris, yes you can.

Comment: For deleting files with the LiveCD, try using `sudo` to remove the directory as root. Run `sudo -H nautilus` to use Nautilus or `sudo rm` on the command line.

Comment: You can also check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/81314/710635) to get an idea about which files to delete.

Comment: when i try open the root directory in the partition of interest, it is apparently empty. my best bet at this stage is probably just save the data off the data partition and nuke it?

Comment: Well, that would be the easiest solution. I probably would have done that.